# Unable to copy cell values

Tags: jquery

On click of the Copy link in a row, I need to create another row and copy all its contents to the new row. This is the code I have:

```
addNewInlineRow(sid, idToUse); // this creates a new row with empty values
//this copies the value from old row to new row
$("#"+rowId+ " td").each(function(index){
    $("#"+idToUse+ " td").get(index).text($(this).text());
});
```

But this code is not working. Any suggestions? I cannot clone the entire TR due to existing complex logic for creating TR id!!

Comment: Have you tried cloning the tr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `.get()` you're retrieving the DOM element, it is not a jQuery object, therefore you can not use `.text()` to set the text value. Try:

```
$("#"+idToUse+ " td").get(index).innerHTML = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clone` method to get the clone of `tr` and append it to the table tbody.

Try this

```
function addNewInlineRow(sid, idToUse){
   var $clone = $("#"+sid).clone();
   $clone.attr("id", idToUse);

   //Now append the clone to table
   $("table").append($clone);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it because I was slow in making a fiddle.  Here it is in case anyone stops by this page: http://jsfiddle.net/gZhdg/

Answer (score 0):

You can still clone the entire tr and then update the parts that need updating (i.e. the ID):

```
function addNewInlineRow(sid, idToUse){
   $('#' + sid).clone().attr('id', idToUse).appendTo('table');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you want to retrieve the values form any containers like **`div,span`**

You must use the `.html()` in jquery.

Try the blow code:

```
 $("#"+idToUse+ " td").get(index).html($(this).html());
```